# VS Code "open file in editor" line number not working. How do I make ctrl + click work with line numbers?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I recently started using docker-compose for local development. The only issue I've been having is that I noticed that using ctrl + click to go to a file line mentioned in the terminal doesn't work. For some reason the text being selected is only the file not the line. Because of that the editor opens the file at the top and not in the line I want. Look at the difference in the 2 pictures bellow. Is this known, is there a solution?

example running locally:
[image: example running locally]

example running docker compose:
[image: example running docker compose]

Comment: the problem matcher/link detector in the terminal use a syntax of `main.py:29`, see if you can change the regex used, and its group matching

Comment: Seems promising. Although I cant find a lot of info on how to do that. Care to point me in the right direction? Im using zsh. Is that something that I should set in the .zshrc?

Comment: when I add a line line `b = 10 / 0` I get a `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` exception, a file path and a line nr, when I hover over the file path also the line nr gets underlined, when I click the editor goes to the correct line nr, do you have PyLance extension installed

Comment: your local terminal has a correct full path, and `line 29` is underlined, the docker terminal has a file that is not found, it looks like a full path but it isn't, if you Ctrl+Click that `account_portfolio.py` do you go to that file, where is that `account_portfolio.py` running, do you have the same extension running as local, if so create an issue at the VSC remote repo

Comment: related source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/46a233646602c378c2168fa2a104dff8e8551558/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminalContrib/links/browser/terminalLinkParsing.ts#L94. It could have to do with priority of pattern matching... but I wonder why you observe different behaviours. Can you please describe more clearly / in more detail what the first screenshot's setup is and what the second screenshot's setup is?

Comment: First screenshot was of a fast api backend running directly on my laptop with no containerization. Second one was also on my laptop but this time using docker-compose. The docker-compose file has the fast api app and a postgres database. @starball